# Как получить запрос с сервера?

Tags: android

Пытаюсь послать запрос и получить ответ следующим образом.

```
String Result_XML;
try {
    Result_XML = SendGET("http://translate.yandex.ru/tr.json/translate?text=lol&lang=en-ru");
    textview5.setText(Result_XML);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
static String SendGET(String site_url) throws IOException
{
    URL url = new URL(site_url);
    URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
    InputStreamReader rd = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
    StringBuilder allpage = new StringBuilder();
    int n = 0;
    char[] buffer = new char[40000];
    while (n >= 0)
    {
        n = rd.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
        if (n > 0)
        {
            allpage.append(buffer, 0, n);                    
        }
    }
    String result = allpage.toString();  
    return result;
}
```

Не работает на версии 4.0.3. На 2.1-2.3.3 работает идеально

Comment: logcat с ошибкой приведите.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov,
http://depositfiles.com/files/mtlxq9trj

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- StackOverflow:[HonyComb and DefaultHttpClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4821845/honycomb-and-defaulthttpclient) и [другие вопросы](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/strictmode)
- [New Gingerbread API: StrictMode](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/12/new-gingerbread-api-strictmode.html)

Речь о том, что сетевые запросы и другие блокирующие операции нужно выполнять в другом потоке, чтоб интерфейс не морозился.

Перенесите код в AsyncTask ошибка пропадет.

Comment: спасибо, все получилось)

Comment: Если ответ устраивает примите ответ

Comment: @Мария_1,
не надо награждать (карма вам пригодится), достаточно галки за принятый ответ и пальца вверх по желанию.